# Existence of periodic orthogonal basis in $L^2([0,1])$ which is not trigonometric?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal, approximation-theory

Let 
$$
\psi(x) := \sin(\pi x).
$$
It is well-known that system $\{ \psi(n x) \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ forms an orthogonal basis in $L^2([0,1])$.

**My question is the following:**

Are there other examples of function $\psi(x)$, such that $\{ \psi(n x) \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ forms an **orthogonal basis** in $L^2([0,1])$ or, at least, orthogonal and complete system in $L^2([0,1])$?

[It is known](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077469698), for instance, that square-wave functions of the form $\mbox{sign}(\sin(n \pi x))$ is complete system in $L^2([0,1])$, however, it is not orthogonal. Of course, one can orthogonalize this system, but the result will be "non-periodic" in the sense that the elements of the orthogonalized set cannot be constructed by replications of the initial function $\mbox{sign}(\sin(\pi x))$.

By the similar reasons Haar system, Legendre polynomials, etc. are not candidates, too.

It seems to me that the question is rather natural and it should be some results on this. However, I cannot find anything. Need your advice!

Comment: The Rademacher functions, if you are willing to accept $\{ r(2^nx)\}$ instead of $\{ r(nx)\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Agree. But for me it is necessary to assume $(nx)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Moreover, I realized that Rademacher system is even not complete.

Comment: It isn't? What is orthogonal to all of them (of course one has to include $r_0$ which is $1$ on $[0,1]$ and $-1$ on $[1,2]$)?

Comment: @DanielFischer To be honest, I didn't study this question. But I believe some textbooks, which I met while searching the answer to the main problem.

Comment: A little bit of thinking about it reveals that for example $\chi_{[0,1/4)}$ is not in the (closure of the) span. Now the difficult question becomes why I thought it was complete ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have found the answer [in this article](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2007/vol8-n2/paper13/v8n2-13pd.pdf).
The main result (restricted to the interval $(0, 1)$) is that **only** 
$$
\{\sin(n \pi x)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \quad \mbox{or} \quad  \{1, \cos(n \pi x)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}
$$
forms a periodic orthogonal basis in $L^2(0, 1)$.

I'll leave this answer here for better search on this question.